# excel sql query - multiple data sources

Tags: sql, excel, db2-400

I would like to make a query that contains data from different servers. For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM SERVER1.SCHEMA1.PRODUCTS

UNION ALL

SELECT *

FROM SERVER2.SCHEMA1.PRODUCTS
```

How do I do that in excel? I get error sql0512 if I write this code, which tell me that the data comes from multiple sources.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to pull data from excel?... If you want to pull data from different server, you must be create link server.

Comment: are both servers DB2 for IBM i (F/K/A  DB2/400?)

Comment: yes charles both servers are db2 400.